# How to use the PINpad to enter the Password in Ncryptoki

Tags: hsm

I'm currently using Ncryptoki C# sample project to test the HSM if it's working. I already setup and initialized the slot and token. When I run the sample code, it always tell me wrong PIN. I use the PINpad to enter the password "1111", any help would be really appreciate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using Cryptware.NCryptoki;

namespace USCToolkit.NCryptokiTest
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        // Creates a Cryptoki object related to the specific PKCS#11 native library 
        //Cryptoki cryptoki = new Cryptoki("smaoscki.dll");
        Cryptoki cryptoki = new Cryptoki(@"C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cryptoki.dll");

        cryptoki.Initialize();

        // Prints all information relating to the native library
        CryptokiInfo info = cryptoki.Info;
        Console.WriteLine(info.Version);    
        Console.WriteLine(info.ManufacturerID);
        Console.WriteLine(info.LibDescription);

        // Reads the set of slots containing a token
        SlotList slots = cryptoki.Slots;
        if(slots.Count == 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("No slot available");
           return;
        }

        // Gets the first slot available
        Slot slot = slots[0];

        // Prints all information relating to the slot
        SlotInfo sinfo = slot.Info;
        Console.WriteLine(sinfo.Description);
        Console.WriteLine(sinfo.ManufacturerID);
        ///
        Console.WriteLine("flags: "+sinfo.Flags);

        if (!slot.IsTokenPresent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No token inserted in the slot: " + slots[0].Info.Description);
            return;
        }

        // Gets the first token available
        Token token = slot.Token;


        // Prints all information relating to the token
        TokenInfo tinfo = token.Info;
        Console.WriteLine(tinfo.Label);
        Console.WriteLine(tinfo.ManufacturerID);
        Console.WriteLine(tinfo.Model);
        Console.WriteLine(tinfo.SerialNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(tinfo.HardwareVersion);





        // Opens a read/write serial session
        Session session = 
            token.OpenSession(Session.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | Session.CKF_RW_SESSION,
                              null,
                              null);

        /////
        //PIN pin = new PIN();
        /////
        // Executes the login passing the user PIN
        int nRes = session.Login(Session.CKU_USER,"1111");
        if (nRes != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong PIN");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Logged in:" + session.IsLoggedIn);

        // Searchs for an RSA private key object
        // Sets the template with its attributes
        CryptokiCollection template = new CryptokiCollection();
        template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
        template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_KEY_TYPE, Key.CKK_RSA));
        template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, "Ugo's new Key"));

        // Launchs the search specifying the template just created
        CryptokiCollection objects = session.Objects.Find(template, 10);

        foreach (Object obj in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((PrivateKey)obj).Label);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((PrivateKey)objects[i]).Label);
        }

        RSAPrivateKey privateKey;
        RSAPublicKey publicKey;

        // If the private key is not found generates the key pair
        if(objects.Count == 0)
        {
            CryptokiCollection templatePub = new CryptokiCollection();
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY));
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_TOKEN, true));
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, "Ugo's new Key"));
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_ID, "1"));
            templatePub.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_MODULUS_BITS, 1024));

            CryptokiCollection templatePri = new CryptokiCollection();
            templatePri.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
            templatePri.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_TOKEN, true));
            templatePri.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
            templatePri.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, "Ugo's new Key"));
            templatePri.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_ID, "1"));

            //Generate the key pair
            Key[] keys = session.GenerateKeyPair(Mechanism.RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN, templatePub, templatePri);
            privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)keys[1];
            publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)keys[0];
        }
        else //If the private key is found gets the corresponding public key
        {
            privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)objects[objects.Count - 1];
            Console.WriteLine(privateKey.Label);

            // search for the related public key
            template = new CryptokiCollection();
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_KEY_TYPE, Key.CKK_RSA));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, "Ugo's new Key"));

            // Launchs the search specifying the template just created  
            objects = session.Objects.Find(template, 1);                 
            publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)objects[0];
            Console.WriteLine(publicKey.Label);

            // prepares for the signature
            string helloworld = "Hello World";
            byte[] text = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(helloworld);

            // launches the digital signature operation with a RSA_PKCS mechanism
            nRes = session.SignInit(Mechanism.SHA1_RSA_PKCS, privateKey);

            // computes the signature
            byte[] signature = session.Sign(text);

            // launches the digital signature verification with a RSA_PKCS mechanism                
            nRes = session.VerifyInit(Mechanism.SHA1_RSA_PKCS, publicKey);

            // verifies the signature
            nRes = session.Verify(text, signature);

            // results if nRes == 0 means that the verification is OK
            Console.Write("Verified " + (nRes == 0));
        }

        // Logouts and closes the session
        session.Logout();
        session.Close();
        cryptoki.Finalize(IntPtr.Zero);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have security officer and ctypto officer, if I plug in SO, it won't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figure out my question. I am working on LunaG5, and when initialize the token(black key), there is a secret text string will be created. The format similar like: Asdf-s4SD-DF7d4-wd3S. This string also used when you install the KSP. The password "1111" is only used on PINpad, but the secret string must be used in the Application to verify which token you used.

```
int nRes = session.Login(Session.CKU_USER,"Asdfs4SDDF7d4wd3S");
if (nRes != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong PIN");
    return;
}
```

For secret string create, search: Creating a Legacy style PED-authenticated Application Partition

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is caused by insufficient validation of return value from `Login` method:

```
int nRes = session.Login(Session.CKU_USER,"1111");
if (nRes != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong PIN");
    return;
}
```

Your code continues only if the value is 0 but underlying PKCS#11 function [`C_Login`](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/LowLevelAPI41/Pkcs11.cs#L436) returns not only [`CKR_OK`](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/Common/CKR.cs#L32) but also [`CKR_USER_ALREADY_LOGGED_IN`](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/Common/CKR.cs#L342) and bunch of other codes that do not necessarily indicate error.

Comment: Hi@jariq, should I covert "1111" to other type? But I need to enter 4 digits "1" on the PINpad. What should I do?

Comment: @ccy try passing `null` instead of string value.

Comment: I think I need to convert "1111" to Hex value

Comment: I checked the login function, it Login(userType As Integer, pin() As Byte) and Login(userType As Integer, pin As String)